# Update order total price by payment method after order was placed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a specific method of payment to manage approval or decline of orders for specific products.

Once order was approved I set order in status "Waiting for payment" and send an email to customer with link to pay.

**The problem is that for some payment method I have to apply a discount.**

I'm able to apply discount before order was placed ( I use it for order that doesn't require approval), but I don't know how to recalcultate the total in this moment.

For do that I use this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','payment_method_discount', 20, 1 );
function payment_method_discount( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    foreach($cart_object->cart_contents as $cart_item_id => $cart_item) {        
      $payment_method_arr = array('ppcp-gateway');
      foreach($payment_method_arr as $payment_method) {
        $percent = 25; 
        $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

        if( $payment_method == $chosen_payment_method ) {   
          WC()->cart->add_fee( 'PayPal fee', 0 - $discount );
        }        
      }    
    }
}
```

To trigger the update I used:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'refresh_payment_methods', 20, 1 );
function refresh_payment_methods() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){ 
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
              $('body').trigger('update_checkout');                            
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I've tried also to add the function refresh_payment_methods to wp_footer hook.

Comment: Please add the code

Comment: The hook `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` affect only the cart object and doesn't have any effect on an exiting order in Order Pay endpoint. You will have to rebuilt something much more complicated specifically for Order Pay, involving certainly Ajax, to be able to remove or add your custom discount in the existing order, refreshing totals…